# Apply style to particular row in a table

Tags: css, stylesheet, html-table

Hi I've a table like below and I wanted to apply style for only tr which is belongs to  section.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>1</th>
            <th>2</th>
            <th>3</th>
            <th>4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>8</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When I try like below it is applying for all trs including  trs.

```
<style type="text/css">
tr
{
height:30px
}
</style>
```

How can I restrict this style to apply only for header part.

Comment: Change the css to `<style type="text/css">
thead tr
{
height:30px
}
</style>`

Comment: Hey Dreamweiver, thank you it is working as expected :)

Answer (score 2):

use,

```
th
{
height:30px
}
```

Or else you can use class

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<style type="text/css">
tr
{
height:30px
}

thead > tr:first-child
{
//put anything you want here
}
</style>
```

Comment: it is applying for both trs, first tr in the header and first tr in the body :(

Answer (score 1):

You can add a class to that tr and specify that class in the css, like this:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr class="give-style">
            <th>1</th>
            <th>2</th>
            <th>3</th>
            <th>4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>8</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And in the css:

```
<style type="text/css">
.give-style
{
height:30px
}
</style>
```

That should do the trick, please choose this as the correct answer if it solves your doubt by clicking on the tick symbol to the left.

Answer (score 1):

use it like this

```
<tr class="my_class">

</tr>
```

then in your CSS, refer it using a "." infront of your classname('my_class')

```
.myclass{
    //your styles go here
}
```